# i combined objects (3 cubes) and add texture

Tags: texturing

Hello guys i just started practicing blender and now im stuck.

i added 3 cubes in the picture combined them using crtl j, and when i add texture, it applied to the 3 cubes like they werent combined.

the first image shown, is that i made objects and didnt combine yet.

[image]

[image]
i combined using crtl j, forming a square with ear shape.

[image]
in adding texture, it is seperated ,

how do i merge to form the shape i want?
so i can fit the face properly.

Comment: If they have the same material and if their UV faces are overlapping, they will display the same thing, but could you please pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: hello, thanks for replying ill send them if i get home, i have no idea about material, if i combine them do i still get 3 materials if i make 3 cubes?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=k2gDZQKl" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/k2gDZQKl/)

Comment: Could you please share the same version of your file as the one you show? Because what I see is not what you show in your screenshots so it's hard to say what's happening

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4sdXq4Gs" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4sdXq4Gs/)

Comment: So as I said you can see that the faces are overlapping, so no wonder why they display the same part of the image, maybe explain a bit more what you want to do, what is the original object and what you want to do with it, etc

Comment: im sorry i dont know how they overlapped, you can see from the last image, im trying to make a head of a dog using cubes only and the texture iam using is pixelated, how do i make the face shape like i wanted to be , like a U shape not the 3 cubes i made, because i thought when you combine objects it should be one property only so i can apply my texture in one go. is there a method besides unwrapping? like merging the uvmap ? (i dont know what you call them), just want to apply the face texture  that has the U shape already directly to the U shape object i made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for what you're trying to do, the best is probably to go in front view, select the front faces of your mesh (in *Edit* mode) and press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project from View*:

[image]

Then in the *UV Editor*, move and scale the UV faces until they match the head picture:

[image]

Do the same for the other sides of the mesh.